# Problems to get only the value of a row within a 2D array Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my sheet I have the range E10:E34 which contains URLS.

I also have the range C10:C34 which contains the references.

In the range I10:I34 the following formula should go:

`=IF(SEARCH("URL";URL cell A1notation);"reference";"")`

This formula, converted to real data, would look like this;

`=IF(SEARCH("https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Mi-vecino-Totoro.jpg";E10);"322";"")`

I am working with Google Apps Script so that it converts the formula automatically with the data of each row, that is, with the URL, the A1notation cell of the URL and the value of the reference.

This is my code so far:

```
function ref_URL_formula3(){

  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hoja = libro.getSheetByName("ImportXML");

  var rangoURLvalor = hoja.getRange('E10:E34').getValues();
  var colURL = 'E';
  var rangoURLnotationCelda = hoja.getRange('E10:E34').getRow();
  var rangoREFvalor = hoja.getRange('C10:C34').getDisplayValues();
  var rangoFormula = hoja.getRange('I10:I34');

  rangoURLvalor.flat().forEach((v, i) => {
      if (v == rangoURLvalor[i][0]) rangoFormula.setFormula('=IF(SEARCH("'+ rangoURLvalor +'";'+ colURL+rangoURLnotationCelda +');"'+ rangoREFvalor +'";"")')
    })
 }
```

Inside the formula, in the URL and in the Reference it does not return the unique value of the row, otherwise i get the all values ​​of the entire range.

Specifically, in the cells of the range I10:I34 this is what I get:

```
=IF(SEARCH("https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Mi-vecino-Totoro.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Kodama-Princesa-Mononoke.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Coco-and-friends.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Dragon-Ball.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/El-Rey-Leon.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/El-Rey-Leon-2.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/El-Rey-Leon-3.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/El-Rey-Leon-4.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Flamingo.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Harry-Potter-1.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Harry-Potter-2.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Harry-Potter-Snitch-Dorada.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Harry-Potter-2.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Harry-Potter-Griffindor.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Minnie.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Star-Wars-2.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Supercats-Hero.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Vis-a-vis-2.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Super-mario.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Gat-y-gos-Gato-y-perro-CatDog.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Rugrats.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Kimetsu-no-Yaiba.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Inuyasha.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Fire.jpg,https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Blue.jpg";E10);"322,323,321,301,303,302,304,319,305,306,307,315,324,308,300,309,311,317,310,316,312,313,314,318,320";"")
```

When what I want to get is this other:

```
=IF(SEARCH("https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Mi-vecino-Totoro.jpg";E10);"322";"")
```

It is clear that there is an error in the path of the rows, however, I really do not know what I am doing wrong.

I am a newbie to Google Sheets and Google Apps Script, so all help is well appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to use a script instead of an array formula that fills a whole column in one go? Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)? Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: The fact that I want to do this with google apps script is because I need to get the visible content of the cell, not the cell itself. I think this cannot be obtained through formulas ... For example, if I do it through formula, it would look something like this: ``` =IF(SEARCH(E10;E10);C10;"") ``` and what I really need is the value, so that it looks like this: ``` =IF(SEARCH("https://collaresmolones.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Mi-vecino-Totoro.jpg";E10);"322";"") ```  @doubleunary

Comment: You can get the visible content in the cell with `rept(E10, 1)`. Consider sharing a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: You can go through rows in a range with an array formula, and use `if()` or `ifs()` to choose what value to return in each row. The same can be done with a script, but there seems to be little point to do so. Consider showing what you have and what you are trying to accomplish by sharing a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arrange all formulas in a map function and put them in a range by using **setFormulas()** function.

```
function ref_URL_formula3(){

  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hoja = libro.getActiveSheet();

  var rangoURLvalor = hoja.getRange('E10:E34').getValues();
  var rangoREFvalor = hoja.getRange('C10:C34').getValues();
  var rangoFormula = hoja.getRange('I10:I34');

  var formulas = rangoURLvalor.map(function (v,i) {

    return ['IF(SEARCH("' + v + '"; E' + (i + 10) + ');' + rangoREFvalor[i] +';"")']

  })

  rangoFormula.setFormulas(formulas) 

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This definitely solved the problem. You have saved me from having to do it manually in over 300 rows. Now I see that the row traversal in the code was doing completely wrong. Without a doubt, I have learned something new today. Again, thank you very much! I mark this answer as valid and vote in favor. @MuhammetYunusTunca

Comment: You're welcome. I'm so glad my second contribution in this site has been founded helpful. :)

Let me explain the "map" method a little more. We use it to manipulate an array. It goes through all items of the array, performs the changes we wish, and returns a new array with these new items. 

One final thing: I didn't understand very well why you need such a thing. Maybe if you share with us a spreadsheet link, we can help you more. 
All the best.